# Redis as logging catch

Tags: logging, redis, real-time, bigdata, in-memory-database

I'm thinking about adding Redis cache to my RT server application as logging solution.
currently my application is using an infra logging solution(to disk) that fail to work under my load causing me latency in my app.

`My average log message is 100B X 10,000 messages per second = 1M logs per second
I need to hold 5 days of logs meaning = 1M X 60 seconds X 60 minutes X 24 hours = 86400MB = 86.4GB X 5 days = **432GB** in memory logging.`

For debugging purpose I need access speeds for the logs.

Do you think redis can work with my numbers?
do you think of a better solution to handle my problem?

10x

Answer (score 0):

By your question I can see that you are aware that we are talking about RAM, right?

By saying this, I mean, this will be very, very expensive, and you don't need it. Besides, with Redis you will have only very limited way of querying it.

It's not a good idea to build such a complex and expensive solution and don't have a good way to query it. :)

My idea is to create a Messaging server. I suggest you to look at SQS from AWS, they will handle the infrastructure for you. If you can't use AWS, maybe you could install RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ inside your structure.

So, this way you could send all your messages to this queue, doesn't matter which one. And then you build a application to consume then and put it inside a Structured Database, I suggest MongoDB. It's fast, robust, can have a good cache, you define it, and also you will use the disk as storage.

Using this solution, you don't have to worry about the throughput of your application, just send the enqueue the messages on the message server, and let the consumer do the nasty job reading from there and sending it to your database solution.